# Reset Score Button iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uilabel

I want displayBatsmenOneScoreLabel to reset to 0 when the resetScoreButton is hit.

What would be my code for the resetScoreButton?

Here's my code.

```
var batsmenOneScoreInt: Int = 0

@IBOutlet weak var displayBatsmenOneScoreLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func BatsmenOneScoreStepper(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    let batsmenOneScoreValue = Int(sender.value)
    displayBatsmenOneScoreLabel.text = String(batsmenOneScoreValue)
}

@IBAction func resetScoreButton(_ sender: Any) {
   //what should I write here...
}
```

Comment: I guess his question is how to reset the label of the button to 0.

Comment: JFI, You should use proper naming convention in programming. Eg. `BatsmenOneScoreStepper` should be `batsmenOneScoreStepper` in this case.:)

Comment: Why just reset the label? Why not also reset the score variable?

Comment: FYI - your `batsmenOneScoreInt` property is never used. You create a local variable of the same name in `BatsmenOneScoreStepper`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@IBOutlet weak var batsmenScoreStepper:UIStepper!   

@IBAction func resetScoreButton(_ sender: Any) {
   batsmenScoreStepper.value = 0.0;
   displayBatsmenOneScoreLabel.text = "\(batsmenScoreStepper.value)"
}
```

you should first take outlet of your `UIStepper` and reset it.

Comment: Thanks. It resets to 0.0. I just want Int 0. I have tried changing the number to just 0 but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset the batsman score, it should work.

You can try this code:

```
    @IBAction func resetScoreButton(_ sender: Any) {

     let batsmenOneScoreValue = 0
        displayBatsmenOneScoreLabel.text = String(batsmenOneScoreValue)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For good practice you should first reset the main variable that is holding the score, and then set that variable to the label.

```
@IBAction func resetScoreButton(_ sender: Any) {
    batsmenOneScoreInt = 0;
    displayBatsmenOneScoreLabel.text = "\(batsmenOneScoreInt)"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can reset score in button's action(touchup inside) like below...

```
@IBAction func resetScoreButton(_ sender: Any) {

   displayBatsmenOneScoreLabel.text = "0"
   //do something here...
}
```

**EDIT:**

In case if you want to reset score variable you need to set `batsmenOneScoreInt = 0` in `resetScoreButton` method.

Comment: You have accepted the wrong answer. You don't want to reset just the label.

Comment: In question it is clearly mentioned that "I want displayBatsmenOneScoreLabel to reset to 0 when the resetScoreButton is hit.".

Comment: @MahendraGP Poor phrasing most likely. What would be the practical use case of doing that? None.

Comment: That's because the OP doesn't seem to understand their actual requirement. If only the label is reset, then the next tap on the stepper will result in the label showing the previous score again (+ or - 1).